# Reading an xls file from a website using a query

Tags: excel, vba

```
' Builds URL for retrieval from web
CurrentDate = Sheet5.Range("A1").Text
NextDayDate = Sheet5.Range("C1").Text
URLFirstPart = "https://docs.misoenergy.org/marketreports/"
URLLastPart = "_da_pr.xls"

URLCurrentDate = URLFirstPart + CurrentDate + URLLastPart
URLNextDayDate = URLFirstPart + NextDayDate + URLLastPart

' Imports day 1 MISO data into "MISO_Day_1_Temp" tab
Set destCell = Sheet22.Range("A1")
Sheet22.Unprotect
With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & URLCurrentDate, Destination:=destCell)
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
destCell.Parent.QueryTables(1).Delete
```

I am having trouble reading an xls file from a website using a query. I believe the problem is with the connection type. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: what error is it generating?

Comment: It is importing giberish data as opposed to actual stuff from the xls file

Comment: Can you provide an example of the date format - from cell A1?